# Mini USB Male to 3.5mm female tips?

Tags: usb, audio, speakers

I got some helmet speakers for free from my work. I was hoping to just install them and them plug in a 3.5mm connection to my phone and play away. But the speakers have a mini usb since you "need" some kind of main hub to connect it to. So i was wondering if there is a way to convert it?

My soldering skills are pretty good but I'm not an expert. Maybe cut the wire and solder a 3.5mm wire would that work?

Or if anyone know of any adapter that will work? Best Regards!

[image]

Comment: Chances are it is digital if on USB and not analog for 3.5mm. So there may be a DSP chip inside you’d have to bypass. Try to Ohm it out

Comment: Ohm it out, What do i look for and between which wires? I doubt that there is a chip inside these small speakers. + It's not the end of the world if i break it haha.

Comment: If they have a USB connector, there must be some electronics in them - perhaps in the USB connector.  To use a 3.5 mm headphone jack, you will have to bypass any electronics and connect directly to the speakers.

Comment: plug the speakers into the usb connector of your phone

Comment: Try a USB port. And test it

Comment: Was it intended for XBOX? Or what call supplier, stop guessing ask for specs or advice

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I just cut the wire, soldered a 3.5mm jack, plugged into my phone and it did work. Very low volume tho. But that's another issue. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If it’s an obsolete Kaliber product ( not on their website) call for tech support.

Toll Free: 866-9-IOGEAR (866-946-4327)
Local: 949-453-8782